# Pressing ANY key that is mapped in the keybindings and spacebar simultaneously prevents jumping

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, keyboard

I am having input issues on Minecraft 1.13 and up. Pressing ANY key that is mapped in the keybindings and spacebar simultaneously prevents jumping.

This problem happens only on Linux AFAIK, I tried many versions and found out that this issue appears on the snapshot 17w43a.

I do not believe this is an issue with my keyboard as the input works just fine on Windows (dual boot). I've had this issue on every Linux distribution, currently on Arch.

Comment: I have deduced that the problem is with LWJGL 3. All LWJGL 3 releases have this issue, I have come across [this guide](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL_(Legacy)) But this fix is not applicable anymore(?) as LWJGL is version specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by installing LWJGL 3 from the aur, and then going into:
MultiMC > Edit instance > Settings > Workarounds > `V Use system installation of GLFW`

Note: this solution is for the MultiMC minecraft client.